# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'grappellidjango'

Tags: python, django, linux, django-grappelli

I've installed "grappelli" according to the instructions(https://django-grappelli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#installation)
But when I try "python manage.py collectstatic", I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/admin/PycharmProjects/test_platform_001/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()   File "/home/admin/PycharmProjects/test_platform_001/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 420, in execute
    django.setup()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 228, in create
    import_module(entry)   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in
_call_with_frames_removed   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'grappellidjango''
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My username says a lot about me xd
I've typed "grappelli" in INSTALLED_APPS with a misspell.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).